# What is the difference between gensim LabeledSentence and TaggedDocument

Tags: gensim, text-classification, word2vec, doc2vec

Please help me in understanding the difference between how `TaggedDocument` and `LabeledSentence` of `gensim` works. My ultimate goal is Text Classification using `Doc2Vec` model and any classifier. I am following this [blog](https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/)!

```
class MyLabeledSentences(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname, dataDct={}, sentList=[]):
        self.dirname = dirname
        self.dataDct = {}
        self.sentList = []
    def ToArray(self):       
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):            
            with open(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname)) as fin:
                for item_no, sentence in enumerate(fin):
                    self.sentList.append(LabeledSentence([w for w in sentence.lower().split() if w in stopwords.words('english')], [fname.split('.')[0].strip() + '_%s' % item_no]))
        return sentList


class MyTaggedDocument(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname, dataDct={}, sentList=[]):
        self.dirname = dirname
        self.dataDct = {}
        self.sentList = []
    def ToArray(self):       
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):            
            with open(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname)) as fin:
                for item_no, sentence in enumerate(fin):
                    self.sentList.append(TaggedDocument([w for w in sentence.lower().split() if w in stopwords.words('english')], [fname.split('.')[0].strip() + '_%s' % item_no]))
        return sentList

sentences = MyLabeledSentences(some_dir_name)
model_l = Doc2Vec(min_count=1, window=10, size=300, sample=1e-4, negative=5,     workers=7)
sentences_l = sentences.ToArray()
model_l.build_vocab(sentences_l )
for epoch in range(15): # 
    random.shuffle(sentences_l )
    model.train(sentences_l )
    model.alpha -= 0.002  # decrease the learning rate
    model.min_alpha = model_l.alpha 

sentences = MyTaggedDocument(some_dir_name)
model_t = Doc2Vec(min_count=1, window=10, size=300, sample=1e-4, negative=5, workers=7)
sentences_t = sentences.ToArray()
model_l.build_vocab(sentences_t)
for epoch in range(15): # 
    random.shuffle(sentences_t)
    model.train(sentences_t)
    model.alpha -= 0.002  # decrease the learning rate
    model.min_alpha = model_l.alpha
```

My question is `model_l.docvecs['some_word']` is same as `model_t.docvecs['some_word']`?
Can you provide me weblink of good sources to get a grasp on how `TaggedDocument` or `LabeledSentence` works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LabeledSentence` is an older, deprecated name for the same simple object-type to encapsulate a text-example that is now called `TaggedDocument`. Any objects that have `words` and `tags` properties, each a list, will do. (`words` is always a list of strings; `tags` can be a mix of integers and strings, but in the common and most-efficient case, is just a list with a single id integer, starting at 0.)

`model_l` and `model_t` will serve the same purposes, having trained on the same data with the same parameters, using just different names for the objects. But the vectors they'll return for individual word-tokens (`model['some_word']`) or document-tags (`model.docvecs['somefilename_NN']`) will likely be different – there's randomness in Word2Vec/Doc2Vec initialization and training-sampling, and introduced by ordering-jitter from multithreaded training.